# References for abstract analysis

Tags: topological-groups, topological-vector-spaces, topological-rings

Reading the [Wikipedia page on functional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_analysis#Foundations_of_mathematics_considerations) I've found the following quote "Abstract analysis. An approach to analysis based on topological groups, topological rings, and topological vector spaces." it cought my interest so I tried to found some references to study it, but I was unable to find something usefull.
So can anyone give me some references?

Comment: Most any functional analysis text, such as [Rudin's](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0070542368) or [Conway's](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0387972455) or [Berberian's](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0387900802) or [Goffman/Pedrick's](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1470429691) or [Bachman/Narici's](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486402517). If you really want to go gung-ho on the abstractness, see [**Topological Uniform Structures**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486658082) by Warren Page (1978; reprinted by Dover Publications in 1988).

Comment: Try searching also the topic Harmonic Analysis.

Comment: Try Folland's real analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the help, especially for the indication of Warren's book, it seems to be exactly what I'm looking for.